# Structlog and logging module not logging with pytest

Tags: python, python-logging, structlog

So I have a testing folder structure (that tests a module `src` not shown here) like this:

```
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_main.py
```

And have the `__init__.py` configure my logging as shown:

```
import structlog, logging, sys
from structlog.testing import LogCapture

logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", filemode="w")

structlog.configure(
    processors=[LogCapture()],
    context_class=structlog.threadlocal.wrap_dict(dict),
    logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    cache_logger_on_first_use=True
)
```

And my `test_main.py` as shown:

```
import logging, structlog, pytest

from src.factories.factories import MyFactory
import src.main
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "factory",
    [
        MyFactory(),
    ],
)
def test_main(path_to_results_folder_fixture_in_conftest, factory):
    structlog.get_logger().info("test")
    no_of_files_function = lambda: sum(1 for _ in Path(path_to_results_folder_fixture_in_conftest).iterdir())
    len_before = no_of_files_function()
    src.main.main("sony", factory, path_to_results_folder)
    assert no_of_files_function() == len_before + 1
```

Then I simply run `pytest test_main.py`. I was expecting the line `structlog.get_logger().info("test")` to produce the line `test` in the `test.log`. However, there's only an empty `test.log` generated. What am I doing wrong? I have configured logging, but structlog seem to not see it. For more information, nothing is also outputted to stdout/console.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure `structlog` to use `LogCapture`, it captures the log entries instead of printing them – that's the whole purpose of it. See also https://www.structlog.org/en/latest/testing.html